# Sorting NSFetchedResultsController using a to-many relationship property

Tags: core-data, one-to-many, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

**SCENARIO**

I have two entities: **Item** and **ListDetail** (which contains prices for different lists for every item). This is absolutely needed and I can't provide a price attribute for the Item entity because every item can have more prices for different dynamic lists (retail, b2b ecc.).

The relationship is:

```m
Item (lists) <------->> (item) ListDetail
```

The current active list in my app change dinamically, so let's say I have an integer variable with the current active list: _ACTIVE_LIST_CODE_. When I need a price for an item object I use an helper method on the Item class:

```m
-(NSNumber*) getPrice {
    NSSet *lists=[self.lists filteredSetUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"listId == %d",_ACTIVE_LIST_CODE_]]; 
    ListDetail *activeList=[[lists allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    return activeList.price;
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

I use a UITableView with NSFetchedResultController in order to select and show some items for different sections. Nothing special. I would like to order the fetchedObjects using the items price for the active list. If price was an attribute of Item I would added simply a sort descriptor to the fetch request like so:

```m
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"price" ascending:YES];
```

But as said before this is not possible, price is a dynamic attribute.

If using transient properties was possible for sort descriptors, I would set a price transient properties calculated on fly using my helper method. Nothing to do.

Using a keypath in the descriptor like "lists.price" is not possible (or maybe I don't know how to do that), just because it's a to-many relationship and it's modeled with a NSSet.

I tried some workaround, without success:

1) observing _ACTIVE_LIST_CODE_ changes to set items price in a non-transient attribute.

2) after the fetch request, before presenting the table view, reorder a brand new array with fetched objects using the transient "price" property, iterate the orderdered array following an ascending integer index "i" and assigning this value to a non-transient property "order" for the Item entity. Using "order" for sort descriptor in the fetch request. (This approach is described here: [Re-ordering NSFetchedResultsController](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/06/05/re-ordering-nsfetchedresultscontroller/))

Both of them works, but they slow down performance because I have thousands of items in the fetch results... Any idea?

Comment: How does 1) slow things down? The active list code supposedly does not change frequently or in bulk, right?

Comment: List code can change when user selects a different client. This occurs not so frequently, but even if once, making a for loop through 50k items, changing price attribute and saving the context freezes the app for 8-9 seconds. This is not acceptable!

Comment: You can do the update on a background thread and update the UI via NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.

Comment: Sure I can, but it would be not a great advantage: items need to be shown immediately after client selection (that means, active list change) so I need the price attribute to be updated and sort items by price.

Comment: This is not logical. Either there is a device change --> huge update --> background thread. Or there is a active list change --> small update --> returns immediately from bg thread.

Comment: Mmm, there's no device change at all... When I talk about "client" I don't mean user: client is an entity of my model. Every client has a list. I need to be more detailed. Think about this scenario: client X selected, active list= LX, user is scrolling items ordered by price.  User taps on "change client", a modal shows user's clients and he selects the new client Y, which has the list LY. Active list change to LY. I need to update the non-transient price property for thousands of items before showing them ordered by price. This is a huge update and forces my app to be freezed.

Answer (score 0):

How about fetching `ListDetail` instead? You could restrict and sort with the appropriate predicates and sort descriptors, exactly as you propose.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = 
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"listID = %@", activeListCode];

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = 
  @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"price" ascending:YES]];
```

Now, to group by some attribute of item should be simple and efficient because it is a to-one relationship. Your fetched results controller's `sectionNameKeyPath` can be something like

```
@"item.category"
```